# What is the correct version of CUDNN for CUDA 11.0

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, cudnn

I want to start using `tensorflow-gpu`, and I looked some stuff up, and found out that I need to ensure that I have both `CUDA` and `CUDNN`. So, I opened up the command prompt and ran the command `nvidia-smi` to check my `CUDA` version:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi
Tue Jun 02 14:13:03 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 445.87       Driver Version: 445.87       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   40C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     77MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU                  PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|                                                                  Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                10488    C+G   ...n64\EpicGamesLauncher.exe    N/A      |
|    0                12636    C+G   ...4\UnrealCEFSubProcess.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now that I see my `CUDA` version is `11.0`, I went to the [NVidia's website](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) to select a version of `CUDNN` that can work with `CUDA 11.0`, but the latest ones support up to `CUDA 10.2` currently. What should I do? Can I use the one for `CUDA 10.2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `nvidia-smi` shows is not the CUDA version that you have installed, but the maximum CUDA version that your driver supports.

CUDA 11.0 has been announced but not released yet (as of June 2nd 2020), so you should use CUDA 10.2 as it's the latest available version.

Comment: I installed CUDA-11.0  I checked also one of its simulation example ./nybody and works fine. But whenever I try to make with opencv(-D WITH_CUDA=ON), my make gives many errors. Whats your opinion about it. Is it cos of opencv not compatible with cuda-11.0?

Comment: Interesting. TF2 only supports up to 10.2, not 11. Unless you want to edit the codebase to support it we all have to wait till TF 2.4. Personally it annoys me but I get it.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of weeks ago, I have upgraded three of them to the new cuda_11.0.2,  Driver 450.51.06 and cuDNN _8.0.
My environment:

1. 86-64
2. Centos 7 with gcc 4.8.5 ( sudo doesn't work in Centos. Login as root)
3. I downloaded cuda_11.0.2-450.51.05_linux.run
   I took a risk but it went fine.  On Nvidia cudnn matrix it said:
   Compute > 3.5, toolkit =11.0 , and driver r450
   So the driver and toolkit minors doesn't matter.
4. Installed, and went through pre-, post- and recommended.
   Everything went fine.
   ****This is very important***
   My cudnn installed but couldn't run the examples.
   If you are an Engineer, you have went through such dilemma because you bypass some small details.
   Gcc 4.8.5 if for installing toolkit and driver.

Cudnn 8.0 needs  gcc 5 and above for c++ 11 or 14 for tool chain.
So what I have done is that( I have a lot of. devtoolset versions in my environment).
I choose  6.0 version instead of 5 to make not be on the border  line.
Re-install it, you will be cool.
***Regarding tensor-flow×××: It has nothing to do with cudnn other than  kera for python if I get this right.